# Apply CSS Module class name by directly accessing the DOM

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

I have a component that makes use of CSS-Modules, by means of the `babel-plugin-react-css-modules` plugin.

At some points during the lifetime of the component I want to be able to calculate new dimensions for it, by accessing the DOM directly.

In my SCSS stylesheet I have a class named `.full-width` that I want to apply to the component's DOM element, in order to make a calculation, and then remove it again.

Now, since adding the class and removing it a fraction of a second later does not affect the component or its state, I want to add and remove the class by directly accessing the DOM and not going through the hoops of somehow relating it to the component's `state`.

If I do `this.DOMReference.classList.add('full-width');` the class `full-width` is added to it, but I want to add the modularised version of the class, as it would be applied if I did `styleName="full-width"` (for example `Component__full-width___Pjd10` )

Is there any way to do this without making `.full-width` a global declaration?

Would I be able to do this with `react-css-modules`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I realised I can import the styles under a variable, instead of anonymously, for example

`import styles from './styles.scss'` instead of `import './styles.scss'` and then I can use it as such

`this.DOMReference.classList.add(styles['full-width']);`

I also don't have to use `styleName="styles.someClass"` either, I can simply use `styleName="someClass"` (as long as there is only one stylesheet file imported, otherwise you need to do it as the former)

Answer (score 0):

**Use in Next.js**

If you use Next.js workes perfect to.

Import CSS Module

```
import styles from './styles.module.css'
```

On your Function

```
element.classList.add(styles['full-width'])
```